# Make Automate Task to manually sync Google Voice

Tags: sync, automation, google-voice

Some network I connect to during my daily life, do not allow for push notifications. So I want to make a task that syncs all my accounts. This was easily done with Llama for Gmail. I just told it when I'm connected to those networks that don't allow push, to sync every 5 minutes. The strange thing is that Google voice is not show up under my google account in settings as a syncing app. You have to actually open the app and click the refresh button.

Does any one know a way to make a manual sync with Google voice in the background? Can I run some intent?